# how to get data not exist in other table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting data based on maintenance_due_date before 7 days or sysdate greater then maintenance_due_date. Now I want to add one more condition that if data not available in maintenace_schedule table against instrument_no and plan_id then also I want to get rows against plan_id from activity_detail table.

```
SELECT
        instrument_no,
        frequency,
        detail,
        plan_id,
        activity_id,
        period,
       -- maintenance_date,
        maintenance_due_date
      FROM
      (
        SELECT
            ms.instrument_no,
            ad.frequency,
            ad.detail,
            ad.plan_id,
            ad.activity_id,
            ad.period,
            -- ms.maintenance_date,
            MAX(ms.maintenance_due_date) maintenance_due_date
        FROM
            maintenance_schedule   ms,
            activity_detail        ad
            --left join maintenance_schedule ms1 on ms1.plan_id = ad.plan_id and ms1.instrument_no = ms.instrument_no --am.inactive <> 1
        WHERE
            ms.instrument_no = 10073
            AND ad.plan_id = 100
            AND ms.plan_id = ad.plan_id
            and ad.end_date is null
            AND ms.activity_id = ad.activity_id
        GROUP BY
            ms.instrument_no,
            ad.frequency,
            ad.detail,
            ad.plan_id,
            ad.activity_id,
            ad.period
            -- ms.maintenance_date
        )
    WHERE
        ( maintenance_due_date BETWEEN sysdate AND sysdate + 7
          OR maintenance_due_date < sysdate)
          order by activity_id asc, maintenance_due_date asc;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output for this sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner query should be changed to use LEFT JOIN so you could handle the null values from a missing row within both of WHERE clauses (inner and outer query). For readability I moved your inner query to CTE definitions and named it *activities*. You don't need to do that - you can leave it where it was if you wish so.
Here are your (imagined) sample data and the new *activities* CTE with some comments in the code:

```sql
WITH
    maintenance_schedule AS
      (   Select 100 "PLAN_ID", 1 "ACTIVITY_ID", To_Date('20.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "MAINTENANCE_DUE_DATE", 10073 "INSTRUMENT_NO", 'some other data' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
          Select 100 "PLAN_ID", 2 "ACTIVITY_ID", To_Date('29.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "MAINTENANCE_DUE_DATE", 10073 "INSTRUMENT_NO", 'some other data' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual 
      ),
    activity_detail AS
      (   Select 1 "ACTIVITY_ID", 100 "PLAN_ID", 'details about ...' "DETAIL", 'frequency X...' "FREQUENCY", 'A' "PERIOD", Null "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
          Select 2 "ACTIVITY_ID", 100 "PLAN_ID", 'details about ...' "DETAIL", 'frequency Y...' "FREQUENCY", 'B' "PERIOD", Null "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
          Select 3 "ACTIVITY_ID", 100 "PLAN_ID", 'details about ...' "DETAIL", 'frequency Z...' "FREQUENCY", 'C' "PERIOD", Null "END_DATE" From Dual 
      ),
    activities AS
      (   SELECT  ms.instrument_no,
                  ad.frequency,
                  ad.detail,
                  ad.plan_id,
                  ad.activity_id,
                  ad.period,
                  MAX(ms.maintenance_due_date) maintenance_due_date
          FROM    activity_detail        ad
          --    LEFT JOIN (line below) is the solution to your problem because it gives you options to handle null values from a missing row
          LEFT JOIN maintenance_schedule   ms ON( ms.plan_id = ad.plan_id And ms.activity_id = ad.activity_id )    
          WHERE   ( Nvl(ms.instrument_no, 10073) = 10073 AND ad.plan_id = 100 AND ad.end_date Is Null)
              --   you can use this --->    ( Nvl(ms.instrument_no, 10073) = 10073 AND ad.plan_id = 100 AND ad.end_date Is Null)
              --   OR this          --->    ( ms.instrument_no = 10073 AND ad.plan_id = 100 AND ad.end_date Is Null) OR ( ms.instrument_no Is Null AND ad.plan_id = 100 AND ad.end_date Is Null)
          GROUP BY  ms.instrument_no,
                    ad.frequency,
                    ad.detail,
                    ad.plan_id,
                    ad.activity_id,
                    ad.period
        )
```

with above data your main SQL shoulld be like below:

```sql
SELECT  instrument_no,
        frequency,
        detail,
        plan_id,
        activity_id,
        period,
        maintenance_due_date
FROM    activities      --      moved your subquery to CTE definition above for readability - you can leave it here if you wish so
WHERE   ( Nvl(maintenance_due_date, sysdate + 1) BETWEEN sysdate AND sysdate + 7 OR maintenance_due_date < sysdate)
    --   you can use this --->        ( Nvl(maintenance_due_date, sysdate + 1) BETWEEN sysdate AND sysdate + 7 OR maintenance_due_date < sysdate)
    --   OR this          --->        ( maintenance_due_date BETWEEN sysdate AND sysdate + 7 OR maintenance_due_date < sysdate OR  maintenance_due_date Is Null)
ORDER BY activity_id, maintenance_due_date
```

... R e s u l t :

| INSTRUMENT_NO | FREQUENCY | DETAIL | PLAN_ID | ACTIVITY_ID | PERIOD | MAINTENANCE_DUE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10073 | frequency X... | details about ... | 100 | 1 | A | 20-DEC-22 |
| 10073 | frequency Y... | details about ... | 100 | 2 | B | 29-DEC-22 |
|  | frequency Z... | details about ... | 100 | 3 | C |  |

Additionaly, you can use, let's say, Nvl(INSTRUMENT_NO , 0) in the SELECT list to give a value for missing data if you want.